# Converting byte[] to JsonObject

Tags: java, android

I want to convert `byte` to `JsonObject`. I tried like this:

```
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
    String testV=new JsonObject(new String(responseBody));
}
```

But I am getting compiler error:

```
JsonObject cannot be applied to java.lang.String
```

How can I do this?

Comment: After the 2nd edit on testV data type from String to JsonObject, it is same as accepted answer and somehow confusing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this :

```
String testV=new JSONObject(new String(responseBody)).toString();
```

or this if you need a `JSONObject`

```
JSONObject testV=new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
```

The issue is that you declare a `String` variable and intent to store a `JSONObject`into it.

Comment: As there are so many available json libs. I believe in above solution you are referring to org.json lib

Comment: How to import JSONObject?

Comment: Like any java import: `import org.json.JSONObject;`

Comment: This didn't work for me, it kept saying my JSON object does not start with a `{`, even when I added a `trim()` method to the String.

Comment: @Azurespot are you sure that you JSON content is valid?

Comment: @GuillaumeBarré thanks, I actually checked the string and it was a Base64 string (needed an image, which is basically a byte[], into string or JSON object format for an API call). I thought it was going to be in JSON, but then found that. Thanks for addressing.

Comment: There is no such constructor accepting a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(responseBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: How to import JSONObject?

Answer (score -1):

```
JSONArray testV = new JSONArray(new String(responseBody));
```

Comment: I need jsonobject. Not jsonArray

Comment: Add some clarification to your answer. Simply posting a code block is not considered a good answer on Stack Overflow.